# Failed to initialize analyzer, Unable to read thread log file - DynamoRIO - DrCacheSim cannot process directory/simulate cache

Tags: python, caching, simulation

I am using **DrCacheSim** (DynamoRIO) to **write raw cache files** for a simple program (python program which I converted into an executable program) and then **simulate the cache** from the raw files. The simulation in most tries **works only for one** of the several directories which are generated when writing cache data for the program.

- OS: **Windows**, but executing commands via **WSL (Ubuntu-22.04)**
- Code Editor: **PyCharm**
- Commands used:

  - ```bash
    "/mnt/c/DynamoRIO/bin64/drrun" -t drcachesim -offline -outdir "$cache_dir" -- "$progr_path"
    ```

    ->Writes **raw cache files** for program under $progr_path
  - ```bash
    "/mnt/c/DynamoRIO/bin64/drrun" -t drcachesim -indir "$D"
    ```

    -> Generates trace-files for every directory with the pattern drmemtrace.*.dir

Errors I get:

- For first directory which cannot be processed:
  Invalid header

  ```bash
  Failed to initialize scheduler: Failed to open /mnt/c/.../drmemtrace.simpleProgram.00715.0207.dir/trace/drmemtrace.simpleProgram.00715.7827.trace.zip  ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: raw2trace failed: Failed to map module /tmp/\_MEIdSeK9R/libz.so.1
  ```
- For second directory which cannot be processed:

  ```bash
  ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: Directory setup failed: Failed sanity checks for thread log   file   /mnt/c/.../drmemtrace.simpleProgram.00715.9530.dir/raw/drmemtrace.simpleProgram.00715.1483.raw.lz4:   Unable to read thread log file
  ```

I have tried including libz.so.1 in the creation of the program from the .py file. I tried modifying the access right via `chmod -R u+rwx` and some other solutions, none of which worked once. I also tried different python code for my program, and tried to run the above mentioned commands on Windows, but got the same errors everytime. What am I doing wrong? Has somebody experienced this?

Python code of the program which is used for cache/trace analysis:

```py
import sys
def multiply(first_number, second_number):
    result = first_number * second_number
    print('First Number: {}, second number: {}, multiplied: {}'.format(first_number, second_number, result))
    return result
multiply(9, 15)
sys.exit()
```